# Experience Cloud Not Displaying User Profile Information

Tags: experience-builder-page

I added the User Profile component to content in Experience Cloud and checked the Properties per Salesforce Help. I get an error "This component has no data. We can't load the User Profile component because it's not supported by any data. Once you add data, reload Experience Builder to see your component."

As the System Administrator and builder/member of the site, I would expect to see my data as the running user. Why can't Experience Builder detect it? User Id in Properties is `{!recordId}`. What else am I missing?

Comment: Do you have it on a user detail page? It should work there, but it won't work anywhere else.

Comment: I also tried on User Profile Detail component. There is no User Detail component and no User object.

Comment: Have you tried setting the User Id property to `{!CurrentUser.id}`?

Answer (score 2):

Using User Id `{!CurrentUser.id}` allows this to work:

[image: UserProfileComponent]

Comment: Did you mean `{CurrentUser.id}` or `{!CurrentUser.id}`?

Comment: I meant `{!CurrentUser.id}` with the bang.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think I was wrong on this one. Try adding it in the Themes area of the Experience Builder. Pic below shows all the details (Select your profile component in the dropdown as shown):

[image: Experience Builder User Profile Config]

Comment: Theme doesn't have Search Component or User Profile Component.

I was able to get data using `{CurrentUser.id}` instead of `{!recordId}` but now the data is formatted badly.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. The page needed to be Object Layout instead of Standard Layout.

Comment: I tried Object layout - it doesn't work for LWR sites. You should have included screenshot especially when dealing with Experience Cloud